# integrate openApi 3 to multi module Spring boot 3 project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger

I have a multi-module spring boot project. Spring Boot's version is 3.2.1. Each of sub-module projects has swagger /v3/api-docs. I want to make a multi group swagger UI in my cloud gateway. But I want to do it with application.yaml. I did all of configs but when I open http://localhost:9000/swagger-ui.html it gets me Whitelabel Error Page. I don't understand what I do wrong.

```
dependencies {
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway'
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.1.0'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'}
```

[image]